# raspberry pi zéro 2

Tags: temperature, security, pi-zero-w-2

I wanted to ask a question. Is there a security system to shutdown the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 in the event of overheating? A hardware solution in the Raspberry Pi(a form of security) and not a software solution (a command line)?

Answer (score 1):

The CPU speed will be throttled if the Pi SoC starts to get too hot.  This should prevent the SoC overheating.  However if the SoC is damaged (e.g. damaged GPIO) this will not prevent overheating.

There is no general protection for the rest of the components on the Pi boards.